# JS Is it possible for fetch to not wait for response?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a logging API in which is executed before a link. The link will be redirecting the user to other place and I'm executing fetch before the user is redirected. So the script is like this now:

```
loggingAPI({
    timestamp: moment()
})
window.location = "http://.......com"
```

The logging api is just a normal fetch wrapper.

However, the server doesn't receive the API request right now. I think it's because of it doesn't even get the chance to send the request to the api.

So can I wait for the request to be sent but not waiting for the response?

Comment: the reason your request isn't being sent is because you change window location straight away - the only way to know a request is sent is to wait for a response

Comment: an alternative **may** be (actually, seems a perfect fit) [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) - which (of course) won't work in Internet Exploder

Comment: @JaromandaX Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: done - was on mobile so adding code is a pain :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question, but if you're using `fetch` you can use the `keepalive` flag.

> The keepalive option can be used to allow the request to outlive the page. Fetch with the keepalive flag is a replacement for the Navigator.sendBeacon() API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#keepalive

Answer (score 6):

Using [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) it's very simple

without seeing the code for you function `loggingAPI` the following is a *best guess*

> Note: `sendBeacon` uses a POST request, so the server side may need to be modified to accept such a request - though, seeing as your `loggingAPI` is sending data, I imagine it is already using `POST` - so this may be a non-issue

somewhere in your code, set up an unload event for windows

```
window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
    sendBeacon("same url as loggingAPI", JSON.stringify({timestamp: moment()}));
}, false);
```

Then, when you

```
window.location = "http://.......com"
```

the `loggingAPI` function gets called for you

edit: sorry, I didn't flesh out the code fully, I missed a few steps!!

Comment: the loggingAPI is only a basic fetch pointing to https://api......com/log. Can you replace it with the sendBeacon code? just to call an example API for completeness sake. I think I'd prefer sendBeacon for simplicity sake

Comment: to get a better answer, please include at least a functional example of `loggingAPI`

Answer (score 3):

You can send the request in a service worker.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Here's some fetch specific information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent

You would register the service worker, and then send a message to it before redirecting.

The upside to the initial complexity is that once you start using service workers, they open up a whole new world of programming;  You will end up using them for much more then queuing up messages to send.

## Step 1 Register a service worker

### index.html

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

## Step 2 Create the service worker script

### service-worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    return Promise.resolve(null)
});
```

## Step 3 Create a listener in server worker script

### service-worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  console.log('message', event.data)
  // call fetch here, catching and responding to what you stashed in the message      
});
```

## Step 4 Send the message before you redirect

### index.html

Just a demo to simulate your client.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({message: 'A LOG MESSAGE'});
  }, 2000)
```

After you put all pieces in place, MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE ALL TABS AND REOPEN, or have chrome dev tools set up to deal with refreshing the worker.

Comment: Do all browsers that support service workers support `sendBeacon`?

Comment: for what the OP is trying to achieve, this seems overkill compared to sendBeacon - and has the same level of browser compatibility

Comment: Safari finally got on board recently.  I hardly think a 5 line script and 4 line message receiver is overkill.

Comment: actually, serviceWorkes are only available in Edge 17, sendbeacon since Edge 14 - and serviceworkers have only partial support in some browsers (android and opera mobile for example)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers.  They all support fetch.  What is not supported across the board is PUSH from servers and background sync.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=beacon - more **full** support across the baord

Comment: if you are on ANY IE neither serviceworkers nor sendbeacon can work (you'd use synchronous XMLHttpRequest in that case anyway - that will never be "removed" from IE)

Comment: You can also use the service worker to present the page from a cache while offline, queue the request, and send a whole bunch when finally online.

Comment: how is that at all relevant to the question? Sure, service workers are a good tool, but it's like using a jack hammer to hang up a picture hook in this case :p

Comment: Navigator.sendBeacon is not a bad idea thougt :)

Comment: It solves the problem, and may offer other benefits to the OP.   He has a logging API; I find it hard to believe he would not leverage the other features as well, especially if he takes his app/api offline.

Comment: @StevenSpungin I'm going to try both options. sendBeacon seems more simpler especially from the example given by Jaromanda X, but you're right. The features in service workers are very attractive and I'd like to leverage it. Although, can you give me an example of requesting a simple API request e.g. to /log using service worker? I'm having a hard time in finding a proper example :(. Should the url goes into the register function?

Comment: I will add an outline to my solution, just for the 'record'.

Comment: @KendrickKesley I posted working example.  Hardly a jack-hammer.  More like a machine-gun for the effort of a water balloon. :)

Comment: Thanks! after looking at the code, I realize that I'd prefer the sendBeacon method as it's so much simple for the question's sake. But I'd like to use service worker too in much more complex cases.

Comment: Amazing answer, ignore these people saying it's overkill, this is extremely valuable to know service workers can do this in addition to beacons